# When finding the minimal polynomials in GF(16), Why the 4th conjugate of α³ becomes α^9?

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields, coding-theory, minimal-polynomials

Shouldn't it be α^18, which in GF(16) simplifies to α^3 since α^15 = 1 in GF16? 
Same is also confusing for the 3rd and 4th conjugate of α^7 while finding the minimal polynomial in GF (16), how they get to have α^13 and α^11?
To make matter easy I am also attaching. [an image for conjugacy classes different roots of GF16](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6l4AN.jpg)

Answer (score 4):

The conjugates, apart from $\newcommand{\al}{\alpha}\al^3$ are $\al^6$, $\al^{12}$ and $\al^{24}=\al^9$. I got these by repeatedly applying the
Frobenius map $x\mapsto x^2$ to $\al^3$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Looks like I was doing the power calculation wrong for the conjugacy class elements. This totally works now. Thanks again.